# Как лучше поступить с условиями?

Tags: java

У меня есть переменная d которую пользователь задает сам, она принимает значения от 1 до 99, каждое число должно исполнять свою роль, например если 1 вывести в Toast уведомление , если 88 то уже что-то другое , как лучше такое сделать? Если не использовать 99 if

Comment: сложите ссылки на обработчики в `Map<Integer, Runnable>` и получайте их оттуда по ключу, например

Comment: @StrangerintheQ о, неплохой способ

Comment: @AntonSorokin приходится, я не люблю классы больше 100 строчек и методы больше примерно 10, я в них долго врубаюсь, цикломатическая сложность и все такое

Comment: @StrangerintheQ кстати вместо `Runnable` можно использовать `Function`
P.S. А, да, это же андроид, тут этого нет :( Или есть?

Comment: @AntonSorokin я отстал от жизни в этом плане, у нас в компании `java 1.6`, восьмерку только недавно собрали из исходников, переезжаем на нее по-тихоньку, я еще не привык =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ `я не люблю классы больше 100 строчек и методы больше примерно 10` - и кстати, map'ом тут ничего не изменить. У него все равно будет 100 put'ов, а код со свитчем будет еще и красивее. Да и вообще, там ни мапы ни свитчи не нужны. Посмотрите его комментарий под моим ответом, все намного проще.

Comment: @AntonSorokin нет, это хранилище я бы получал через DI и добавлял бы обработчики не классом-простынёй, а ближе к логике связанной с ними, короче в разных классах

Comment: @StrangerintheQ CDI же? Ну, для новичка как то слишком, тем более не знаю, есть ли CDI в андроиде

Comment: @AntonSorokin я имел ввиду Dependency Injection, в ведроиде это https://google.github.io/dagger/, например

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам следует использовать оператор `switch`:

```
switch(intVariable) {
    case 1: 
        // действие;
        break;
    case 2: 
        // действие;
        break;
    case 3: 
        // действие;
        break;
    //...
    case 99: 
        // действие;
        break;
}
```

Это если все действия разные и не зависят от значения переменной(именно действия, а не их выполнение). Если все действия однотипные - возможно, их можно оптимизировать.

Можно сделать так, как [предлагает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/976834/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8/976838#comment1641039_976834) [Stranger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188366/stranger-in-the-q). С Java 8 можно использовать лямбды:

Сначала создаем `Map<Integer, Consumer> switchMap`, или с каким нибудь другоим функциональным интерфейсом(сейчас - `Consumer`), зависит от *действий*, пишите в комментариях какие конкретно действия нужно сделать, я подкорректирую код.
От ФИ зависит то, какое именно действие будет - возвращающее значение, не возвращающее значение, какое именно будет возвращаться значение, сколько параметров приниматься, и т.п. Действие - это все что угодно, что можно написать в обычном методе

Заполняем его лямбдами:

```
switchMap.put(1, m -> System.out.println("Введена "+m+", проверка проверка"));
//...
switchMap.put(99, m -> System.out.println("Введена "+m+", (: "));
```

А потом просто вызывать `switchMap.get(myIntVariable).accept(myIntVariable);`.

Comment: У меня есть таймер, и в зависимости от того если например пользователь введет 1, значит таймер должен считать до 1-й минуты и останавливаться, в роли таймера использую Chronometer

Comment: использую метод onChronometerTick который отслеживает какая секунда идет, в переменную(elapsedMillis) я записываю это значение (сейчас в коде использую if(elapsedMillis>60000)... тогда код который должен выполниться) , но так как значение может быть от 1 - 99(минут) значит столько и сценариев

Comment: @KzzxD ааа, ну тогда способы выше из ответа вам отлично подходят

Comment: @KzzxD P.S. Если ответ решил проблему, то примите его, нажав на галочку рядом с ним, и плюсаните его, нажав на стрелку вверх рядом с ним

Comment: хорошо спасибо огромное, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал как-то так...

Вместо чисел лучше использовать перечисления `enum`, это добавляет в код читабельность, куда понятнее когда встречаешь название действия, чем его порядковыq номер

Типы событий:

```
public enum HandlerType {
    ALPHA,
    BETA,
    GAMMA,
    DELTA
}
```

Класс с обработчиками:

```
public class Handlers extends HashMap<HandlerType, Runnable> {

    public void run(HandlerType t){
        Runnable handler = get(t);
        if (null == handler)
            return;
        get(t).run();
    }
}
```

Вариант использования:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Handlers handlers = new Handlers();

    handlers.put(HandlerType.ALPHA, () -> {
        System.out.println("running ALPHA");
    });

    handlers.put(HandlerType.BETA, () -> {
        System.out.println("running BETA");
    });

    handlers.put(HandlerType.GAMMA, () -> {
        System.out.println("running GAMMA");
    });

    handlers.put(HandlerType.DELTA, () -> {
        System.out.println("running DELTA");
    });

    handlers.run(HandlerType.ALPHA);
    handlers.run(HandlerType.BETA);
    handlers.run(HandlerType.GAMMA);
    handlers.run(HandlerType.DELTA);
}
```

Результат:

> ```
> running ALPHA
> running BETA
> running GAMMA
> running DELTA
> ```

Comment: Но тогда мне нужно 99 таких
    ALPHA,
    BETA,
    GAMMA,
    DELTA
    ...
да?

Comment: @Stranger, я добавил в свой ответ как бы я реализовал ваше предложение с лямбдами

Comment: @KzzxD да и в таком виде легче понять что они означают